# Get variables' types at runtime in C

Tags: c, reflection, casting, type-conversion, allocation

Can I get in C the program variables' types those existing in a specific memory segment at runtime.

C Does not recognize the error in:

```
int k=5;
float s= 3.4;
k=s;
printf("%d", k);
```

I am trying to change the variables' types at runtime.

Comment: For a better audience switch the tag dynamic-linking with the `c` tag.

Comment: C is statically typed and it has no reflection mechanisms.

Comment: This is called [implicit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#Implicit_type_conversion) typecasting or type conversion in `C`. Data of one or more subtypes can be converted to a supertype as needed at runtime so that the program will run correctly. In your code conversion from float to int causes `truncation` of fractional part.

Comment: @SunEric, no you got the vocabulary wrong. As your link suggest, this is not called implicit cast, but conversion. A cast is by definition an explicit conversion.

Comment: That's an implict cast, where the float is converted to an int, as though you explicitly put a `(int)` cast before it. A variable's type doesn't change in C, since C is a statically typed language.

Comment: AFAIKS, there is no error in your program.

Comment: I was a little bit misunderstood. I need to retrieve and change the types of variables stored in the data segment at runtime, depending even on Operating system functions or Assembly ones, is there away to do so?

Comment: I have tried the bash command nm and Objdump to get the program allocated variables addresses and sizes in the .data and .bss. But it is not enough. Additionally, in which compilation step the 3.4 has been modified to 3?

Answer (score 3):

C is a static type language, you can't change a variable's type. This code:

```
int k=5; 
float s= 3.4; 
k=s;   //type conversion
```

didn't change `k`'s type, `k` is still of type `int`, all it does is to convert the `float` **value** (`3.4f`) to an `int`(which is `3`), and assign that `int` **value** to `k`.

BTW, there's another type conversion in the code above, that is:

```
float s = 3.4;
```

because `3.4` is of type `double`.

Comment: What I need now, is a way to retreive the variables allocated in the data segment, with a reference to those variables. If it is the Operating system which manages the virtual memory variables at runtime, How can I use the capabilities of the Operation system?   Int variables have 32 bits which is the same of float variables. When I use MN Commandin Linux bash, or Objdump Command.. I get just the address of the variable beggining bit. then, how can the operating system differentiate between int & float?

Comment: @hassanLOULOU The **compiler** is the one knows the type of the variables. I didn't get exactly what you are trying to achieve, but you can't get this done from your own program.