# C: Is it possible to find the data type of a variable just by knowing its address

Tags: c, types

In C, is it possible to find the data type of a variable just by knowing its address?

For eg, I am trying to create a table of type:

```
{
    int id,
    void *ptr_to_var,
    float conversion
}


/*Id  Variable  Conversion_formula*/
{
  {0x01, &var_1,  0.4},
  {0x05, &var_2,  0.2}
}
```

... so on

Then, I need to access the content of these variables and apply some conversion.
The variables(var_1, var_2) could be declared else where with different data types.

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: This could be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please tell us what you are _actually_ trying to achieve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get variables' types at runtime in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19753407/get-variables-types-at-runtime-in-c)

Comment: So how would this work with struct and other complex data types? Those typically start on the same alignment as unsigned long or double.

Comment: If `var_1`, `var_2`, etc. can have different types, you need to encode the type in your table somehow, so that the code that uses the table can work out what type the pointer is pointing to.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. Yes, you are right . It is not possible to know the datatype of the variable if only its address were known. Hence I have added a column where I mention the data type explicitly. The solution works, but it is not as neat as I had hoped.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to find out the data type of a variable given its address as a `void*`. This inability drives many design decisions in C library API, such as the requirement to provide a matching format specifier in `scanf` for types that differ only in length (`float` vs. `double`, `int` vs. `short` vs. `long long`, etc.)

In order to make this decision possible the caller needs to provide specific type information in some way, for example

```
enum var_type {
    vt_float
,   vt_double
,   vt_int
,   vt_long
};
struct mystruct {
    int id,
    var_type type;
    void *ptr_to_var,
    float conversion
};
...
{
    {0x01, vt_float, &var_1,  0.4}
,   {0x05, vt_int,   &var_2,  0.2}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

no - you need to store the type of your pointer somewhow. you cant magically detect it.

as a not plain C like workaround you could use  object oriented programming and define an interface to access unknown subclasses

Comment: Hi thanks, yes I realised that after some research :) I have add a field to mention the data type now.